# Apps such as Timeservice are getting automatically installed but Unknown sources option is disabled already

Tags: installation, malware

This has been happening for many days. Some applications are getting installed without my permission, even though I've disabled the 'Unknown Sources' option in Security Settings. Also, I've installed Application Install Blocker and other applications can't be installed, but apps named *Timeservice*, *Data* and others get installed.

Comment: You are probably the victim of system-level spyware. Please refer to the question linked in @Firelord's comment.

Comment: Is your phone rooted? What version of Android does it run?